# How to wait for file upload stream to complete in Akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Recently I started using Akka and I am using it to create a REST API using Akka HTTP to upload a file. The file can have millions of records, and for each record I need to perform some validation and business logic. The way I have modeled my actors are, the root actor receives the file stream, converts bytes to String and then splits the records by line separator. After doing this it sends the stream (record by record) to another actor for processing, which in turn distributes the records to other actors based on some grouping. To send the steam from the main root actor to the actor for processing I am using [`Sink.actorRefWithAck`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Sink/actorRefWithAck.html).

This is working fine for a small file, but for a large file what I have observed is, I am getting multiple chunks and the first chunk is getting processed. If I add `Thread.sleep` for a few seconds based on the load, then it is processing the whole file. I am wondering if there is any way I can know if the stream has been consumed by the processing actor completely so that I don't have to deal with `Thread.sleep`. Here is the code snippet that I have used:

```
val AckMessage = DefaultFileUploadProcessActor.Ack
val receiver = context.system.actorOf(
  Props(new DefaultFileUploadProcessActor(uuid, sourceId)(self, ackWith = AckMessage)))
// sent from stream to actor to indicate start, end or failure of stream:
val InitMessage = DefaultFileUploadProcessActor.StreamInitialized
val OnCompleteMessage = DefaultFileUploadProcessActor.StreamCompleted
val onErrorMessage = (ex: Throwable) => DefaultFileUploadProcessActor.StreamFailure(ex)

val actorSink = Sink.actorRefWithAck(
  receiver,
  onInitMessage = InitMessage,
  ackMessage = AckMessage,
  onCompleteMessage = OnCompleteMessage,
  onFailureMessage = onErrorMessage
)

val processStream =
  fileStream
    .map(byte => byte.utf8String.split(System.lineSeparator()))
    .runWith(actorSink)

Thread.sleep(9000)
log.info(s"completed distribution of data to the actors")
sender() ! ActionPerformed(uuid, "Done")
```

Any expert advice on the approach I have taken will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can make use of Futures of scala. you just send the chunk of your file to actor and on the complition of that chunk's s processing send the next one to the actor. Use Future.onComplete and in the sucess you can do an ask call.

Comment: Hi Raman, thanks for your response on this. As I am using Sink.actorRefWithAck in the flow, I am not able to control sending individual chunks to the processing actor. Are you saying doing that without Sink.actorRefWithAck or there is an way to control individual chunks with Sink.actorRefWithAck

Comment: i am saying to do it without Sink i mean you can do it in parallel using ask calls if the order of the chunks doesn't matter if it does then you will have to do it sequentially that is send next chunk after one is processed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Source with only one file you can await the stream completion by awaiting Future which is returned from runWith method.

If you have Source of multiple files, you should write something like:

```
filesSource
  .mapAsync(1)(data => (receiver ? data).mapTo[ProcessingResult])
  .mapAsync(1)(processingResult => (resultListener ? processingResult).mapTo[ListenerResponse])
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have only one source. When I am using runWith(actorSink) in my example, it is not returning awaiting future. I am getting Awaiting Future when I am using Sink.ignore instead of actorSink that I created using Sink.actorRefWithAck. When I am using Sink.actorRefWithAck I don't have the option to send message with "?" explicitly. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Jeffrey Chung already wrote the right answer. The key thing is to pass right materialized value through stream flows. Or you can add into the receiver some listeners registration logic for OnCompleteMessage event.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `fileStream` is a `Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]`, one idea is to retain the materialized value of the source, then fire off the reply to `sender()` once this materialized value has completed:

```
val processStream: Future[IOResult] =
  fileStream
    .map(_.utf8String.split(System.lineSeparator()))
    .to(actorSink)
    .run()

processStream.onComplete {
  case Success(_) =>
    log.info("completed distribution of data to the actors")
    sender() ! ActionPerformed(uuid, "Done")
  case Failure(t) =>
    // ...
}
```

The above approach ensures that the entire file is consumed before the sender is notified.

Note that Akka Streams has a [`Framing`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-cookbook.html#parsing-lines-from-a-stream-of-bytestrings) object that can parse lines from a `ByteString` stream:

```
val processStream: Future[IOResult] =
  fileStream
    .via(Framing.delimiter(
      ByteString(System.lineSeparator()),
      maximumFrameLenght = 256,
      allowTruncation = true))
    .map(_.ut8String)
    .to(actorSink) // the actor will have to expect String, not Array[String], messages
    .run()
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey Chung, fileStream
    .map(_.utf8String.split(System.lineSeparator()))
    .to(actorSink)
    .run() - this is returning IOResult, not Future[IOResult]. Am I doing something wrong? Another thing related to Framing object, it is expecting maximum frame length. In my file the rows are dynamic. in some cases I have very few characters and in some cases I have many more characters. Initially I tried with 256 and then I had to adjust this based on the data in the file. Because of that I thought to go by the other approach. Any best practices around this

Answer (score 0):

The `receiver` actor will receive the `OnCompleteMessage` or `onErrorMessage` when the stream has been completed successfully or with failure, so you should handle those messages in the `receive` block of the receiver `DefaultFileUploadProcessActor` actor.